# Python Caesar and Vigenere Ciphers

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, caesar-cipher, vigenere

For my programming class, I've been instructed to create two programs, each using the same two helper functions: `alphabet_position(letter)` and `rotate_character(char, rot)`. One function uses the Caesar cipher to encrypt a message with a number of rotations, each given from the command line. The second program is meant to put more use to my Caesar program by turning it into the Vigenere Cipher. Both programs are meant to ignore (i.e., not rotate) special characters and I don't think numbers matter either. However, if the input letter is capitalized, the rotated output letter should be as well.

I've run into several issues with my code: My Caesar program only prints *some* capital letters. For example, with the arguments `Hello, World!` and `4`, I receive an output of `Lipps, svph!` and I cannot figure out why that last capital letter isn't printing. When I attempt to pass in `pYthon` with `26` rotations, my program prints nothing.

My Vigenere program is also doing an odd thing with capital letters: with the passed arguments being `Hello, World!` and `boom`, I receive `Iszxp, mr!`.

Assignment is due in 48 hours and I'm kind of freaking out.  Any and all help, criticism, etc. is welcome!

```
def alphabet_position(letter):
    """receives a letter and returns the 0-based numerical position of that letter within the alphabet."""
    letter = letter.lower()
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    numerical_pos = alphabet.find(letter)

    return numerical_pos

def rotate_character(char, rot):
    """receives a character and an int 'rot', and rotates char by rot number of places to the right."""
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    alpha_dict = dict(enumerate(alphabet))
    new_char = ""
    # ignore and return non-alphabetic characters
    if char not in alphabet:
        return char
    # temporarily convert case to locate in alphabet
    temp_char = char.lower()
    if temp_char in alphabet:
        # get original position of letter
        orig_pos = alphabet_position(temp_char)
        # take char, add rot to its index, mod 25 - 1
        new_pos = (int(orig_pos) + int(rot))
        if new_pos > 25:
            new_pos = (new_pos % 25) - 1
        elif new_pos < 0:
            # avoid negative index error when rot is 26
            new_char = char
        # converting new_pos back to alpha
        else:
            new_char = alpha_dict[new_pos]
        # if original char was upper/lower, return corresponding case for new_char
        if char.islower():
            new_char.lower()
        else:
            new_char.upper()
        return new_char
```

---

```
from helpers import alphabet_position, rotate_character
# ------
# caesar cipher
# ------

def encrypt(text, rot):
    new_text = ""
    for char in text:
        new_char = rotate_character(char, rot)
        new_text += str(new_char)

    return new_text

def main():
    input_text = input("Enter a sentence to encrypt: ")
    input_rot = int(input("Number of rotations: "))

    print(encrypt(input_text, input_rot))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

```
from helpers import alphabet_position, rotate_character
# ------
# vigenere cipher
# ------
def encrypt(text, rot):
    lower_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    upper_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    keystream = 0
    encrypted = ""
    rot.lower()
    for i in range(len(text)):
        keychar = keystream % len(rot)
        if text[i] in lower_alphabet:
            new_char = rotate_character(text[i], alphabet_position(rot[keychar]))
            new_char.lower()
            encrypted += new_char
            keystream += 1
        elif text[i] in upper_alphabet:
            new_char = rotate_character(text[i], alphabet_position(rot[keychar]))
            new_char.upper()
            encrypted += new_char
            keystream += 1            
        else:
            encrypted += text[i]
        # stuck around here... vigenere isn't printing shifted capital letters and I
        # can't figure out why.
    return encrypted

def main():
    input_text = input("Enter a sentence to encrypt: ")
    input_rot = input("Enter your keyword: ")

    print(encrypt(input_text, input_rot))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: helper functions edited to make code cleaner... Now it's only printing the one capital letter when I input `pYthon` with `4` rotations in Caesar. I'm lost.

Comment: Hint: You only need one cased  alphabet to find positions of any character. And there's an `str.islower` function you can write a if else on

Comment: Will that do much else besides make my code look cleaner? (genuine question)

Comment: Well, it'll help create a [mcve], which is encouraged to be posted to isolate the issue

Comment: Additional tip: Pycharm or Eclipse have great debugging features that allow you to run your code line by line and watch what the variables are being assigned to

Comment: Thanks! I use VSCode but the debugging feature can be a little harder to follow. I edited my code to make the suggested changes but I may have made it worse. Feeling like a lost cause. lol

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Python

Comment: As pointed, try a minimal example, what should `rotate_character('z', 1)` or `('z', 26)` return? It looks like it gives a empty string. Loop over all possible characters. Try the very ends of the alphabet. Test that common values like 26 actually return the same exact letter.

Comment: `new_pos = (new_pos % 25) - 1`. Hmm, that's an interesting alphabet, with just 25 characters starting at -1.

Comment: `if char not in alphabet:` um, your alphabet is only lowercase chars. Don't you need to do this test *after* converting t lowercase?